# Does anyone know of a Urwid like environment that is cross-platform for Python 3.x?

Tags: python, cross-platform, python-3.x

I would like it to run on Linux, OS X, and Windows (XP/Vista/7).

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're out of luck until Urwid itself is ported to Python 3 (and according to [this post](http://www.mail-archive.com/urwid@lists.excess.org/msg00503.html) from last month, "the real work to port to python 3 hasn't 
started yet").

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably to use [2to3](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) to convert Urwid itself.

Answer (score 0):

Help port Urwid to Python 3! That is most likely more work that just running 2to3 on it, though.